# spark scala - Group by Array column

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, mapreduce

I am very new to spark scala. Appreciate your help.. 
   I have a dataframe

```
val df = Seq(
  ("a", "a1", Array("x1","x2")), 
  ("a", "b1", Array("x1")),
  ("a", "c1", Array("x2")),
  ("c", "c3", Array("x2")),
  ("a", "d1", Array("x3")),
  ("a", "e1", Array("x2","x1"))
).toDF("k1", "k2", "k3")
```

I am looking for a way to group it by k1 and k3 and collect k2 in an array. 
   However, k3 is an array and I need to apply contains (rather than exact 
   match) for the grouping. In other words, I am looking for a result something 
   like this

```
k1   k3       k2                count
a   (x1,x2)   (a1,b1,c1,e1)     4
a    (x3)      (d1)             1
c    (x2)      (c3)             1
```

Can somebody advise how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to *group by k1 column*, *collect list of structs of k2 and k3*, *pass the collected list to a udf function* for counting when an array in k3 is contained in another array of k3 and adding elements of k2.

Then you can use `explode` and `select` expressions to get the desired output

Following is the complete working solution

```
val df = Seq(
  ("a", "a1", Array("x1","x2")),
  ("a", "b1", Array("x1")),
  ("a", "c1", Array("x2")),
  ("c", "c3", Array("x2")),
  ("a", "d1", Array("x3")),
  ("a", "e1", Array("x2","x1"))
  ).toDF("k1", "k2", "k3")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def containsGoupingUdf = udf((arr: Seq[Row]) => {
  val firstStruct =  arr.head
  val tailStructs =  arr.tail
  var result = Array((collection.mutable.Set(firstStruct.getAs[String]("k2")), firstStruct.getAs[scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String]]("k3").toSet, 1))
  for(str <- tailStructs){
    var added = false
    for((res, index) <- result.zipWithIndex) {
      if (str.getAs[scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String]]("k3").exists(res._2) || res._2.exists(x => str.getAs[scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String]]("k3").contains(x))) {
        result(index) = (res._1 + str.getAs[String]("k2"), res._2 ++ str.getAs[scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String]]("k3").toSet, res._3 + 1)
        added = true
      }
    }
    if(!added){
      result = result ++ Array((collection.mutable.Set(str.getAs[String]("k2")), str.getAs[scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String]]("k3").toSet, 1))
    }
  }
  result.map(tuple => (tuple._1.toArray, tuple._2.toArray, tuple._3))
})

df.groupBy("k1").agg(containsGoupingUdf(collect_list(struct(col("k2"), col("k3")))).as("aggregated"))
    .select(col("k1"), explode(col("aggregated")).as("aggregated"))
    .select(col("k1"), col("aggregated._2").as("k3"), col("aggregated._1").as("k2"), col("aggregated._3").as("count"))
  .show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+---+--------+----------------+-----+
|k1 |k3      |k2              |count|
+---+--------+----------------+-----+
|c  |[x2]    |[c3]            |1    |
|a  |[x1, x2]|[b1, e1, c1, a1]|4    |
|a  |[x3]    |[d1]            |1    |
+---+--------+----------------+-----+
```

I hope the answer is helpful and you can modify it according to your needs.

Comment: I tried this but got into performance issue while running on 5gb data. Any clue on how to optimize? Lot of shuffling is going on which is eating up processing time.