# How to display grouped data in Scala Dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, databricks

I am a beginner in Scala, and I have a dataframe that looks like this (abbreviated):

```
root
 |-- contigName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- start: long (nullable = true)
 |-- end: long (nullable = true)
 |-- names: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- referenceAllele: string (nullable = true)
 |-- alternateAlleles: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

I am trying to simply `groupBy` the names column:

`display(dataframe.groupBy("names"))`

a very simple operation, but

```
notebook:1: error: overloaded method value display with alternatives:
  [A](data: Seq[A])(implicit evidence$1: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[A])Unit <and>
  (dataset: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[_],streamName: String,trigger: org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger,checkpointLocation: String)Unit <and>
  (model: org.apache.spark.ml.classification.DecisionTreeClassificationModel)Unit <and>
  (model: org.apache.spark.ml.regression.DecisionTreeRegressionModel)Unit <and>
  (model: org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeansModel)Unit <and>
  (model: org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeansModel)Unit <and>
  (documentable: com.databricks.dbutils_v1.WithHelpMethods)Unit
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset)
display(dataframe.groupBy("names"))
```

how can I display this grouped data?

Some of the solutions I've seen posted have been very complex, I don't think that this is a duplicate, what I want is extremely simple.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spark scala - Group by Array column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50672206/spark-scala-group-by-array-column)

Comment: first, you cannot group over an `array` column, second you need to add an aggregation to create a `DataFrame` from the `RelationalGroupedDataset`

Comment: @RaphaelRoth would you be able to show an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`groupBy` returns `RelationalGroupedDataset`. You need to add any aggregation function (e.g. `count()`)
`dataframe.groupBy("names").count()` or `dataframe.groupBy("names").agg(max("end"))`

If you need to group by each name, you can explode the "names" array before `groupBy`

```
dataframe
    .withColumn("name", explode(col("names"))) 
    .drop("names")
    .groupBy("name")
    .count()    // or other aggregate functions inside agg()
```